# buttons equally space between them (horizontally)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My code is

```
<div class="buttons">
<input id="date" type="date" name="Date">
<button id="ShowAll">Show All</button>
<button id=" showvalid">Show Valid</button>
<button id=" showpending">Show Pending</button>
<button id=" save">Save</button>
<button id=" clear">Clear</button>
<button id=" downloadascsv">Download As CSV</button>
```

I want those input date and buttons equi space horizontally in `class="buttons"` div. I tried many tricks from google but none worked as those buttons were not of equi width. I tried placing buttons in separate div's and make div's as width=14.2(100/7) but I got result as shown below[image] that didnt worked as all buttons are not of equal width. Basically by expectation is as show[image]
Where 'd' is the any equi distance between the elements.
In this case I have buttons, what should I do if I have `display:block` or `inline` or `inline-block` elements to space equal horizontally and to space equal vertically. Please give your answers for responsive webpage.

Comment: Please check htis link:-https://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/

Comment: you can wrap them in a div and have that div display:flex

Comment: check this if it could help you  http://codepen.io/sahithiK/pen/ObyZbR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to use flex box, you may use text-align:justify and a pseudo to trigger it on a single line.

```css
.buttons {
  text-align:justify;
}
.buttons:after {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:99.5%;/* generates an extra transparent line */
}
/* makeup*/
.buttons {
  min-width:45em;
  padding: 1.2em 1em 0;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px;
  margin:1em;
  border-radius:0.25em;
}
```

```html
open snippet in full page :)
<div class="buttons">
<input id="date" type="date" name="Date">
<button id="ShowAll">Show All</button>
<button id=" showvalid">Show Valid</button>
<button id=" showpending">Show Pending</button>
<button id=" save">Save</button>
<button id=" clear">Clear</button>
<button id=" downloadascsv">Download As CSV</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You read my mind of not using flex but i dont know about pseudo elements. Can you explain your answer, why you added pseudo element after and why you added `text-align:justify` to .buttons class though it is of `display:block`. (I think text-align effect only inline elements, am i wrong?)

Comment: @jayachandrachillipuri text-align has effects  inside the tag on text, img, inputs(any inline/inline-block elements). `justify`, sprays usually words with equals gaps in between each. But it doesn't work on the last line (a single line is also the last :) ). The pseudo here is added to generate a second line. and displayed inline-block so you can size it to use a whole line by itself. The last line of text is not anymore the last one and text-align come efficient.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use "flexbox" then:

```
<div class="buttons-flex">
        <input id="date" type="date" name="Date">
        <button id="ShowAll">Show All</button>
        <button id=" showvalid">Show Valid</button>
        <button id=" showpending">Show Pending</button>
        <button id=" save">Save</button>
        <button id=" clear">Clear</button>
        <button id=" downloadascsv">Download As CSV</button>
    </div>

         .buttons-flex {
             display: -webkit-flex;
             display: flex;
             -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
             justify-content: space-between;
         }
```

If you need to support old browsers (like IE9) and can't use "flexbox", then there is no 100% solution, the best you can get in this case is probably something like this:

```
<div class="buttons-table">
        <div>
            <input id="date" type="date" name="Date">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="ShowAll">Show All</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id=" showvalid">Show Valid</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id=" showpending">Show Pending</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id=" save">Save</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id=" clear">Clear</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id=" downloadascsv">Download As CSV</button>
        </div>
    </div>

         .buttons-table {
             display: table;
             width: 100%;
             table-layout: fixed;
             text-align: center;
         }
         .buttons-table div {
             display: table-cell;
         }
```

To check vendor prefixes and browser support of "flexbox" refer to http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Answer (score 2):

Use display:flex and justify-content:space-between

check this snippet

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <input id="date" type="date" name="Date">
  <button id="ShowAll">Show All</button>
  <button id=" showvalid">Show Valid</button>
  <button id=" showpending">Show Pending</button>
  <button id=" save">Save</button>
  <button id=" clear">Clear</button>
  <button id=" downloadascsv">Download As CSV</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use display flex in your parent div and in your buttons insert a margin value.

https://jsfiddle.net/a20eavga/2/

```
<div class="buttons">
  <input id="date" type="date" name="Date">
  <button id="ShowAll">Show All</button>
  <button id=" showvalid">Show Valid</button>
  <button id=" showpending">Show Pending</button>
  <button id=" save">Save</button>
  <button id=" clear">Clear</button>
  <button id=" downloadascsv">Download As CSV</button>
</div>

.buttons{
  display:flex;
}

button, input {
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the padding and margin as well.